# Trying to link a form and php file together. Not getting an email. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4, sendmail

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 offset-lg-1">
                <div class="impl_con_form">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                        <h1>get in touch</h1>
                    </div>
                    <form action="sendmail.php" method="POST" class="contact-form" novalidate="novalidate">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control require" placeholder="YOUR NAME">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control require" placeholder="YOUR EMAIL" data-valid="email" data-error="Email should be valid.">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="SUBJECT">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="YOUR MESSAGE"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="response"></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                            <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="contact">
                            <button type="submit" data-type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The Code above is a contact form for one of my practice projects im working on. Im trying to get it to link with my sendmail.php file and send it to my current email address but im not having any luck.

```
  <?php
if( isset($_POST['submit']))

$to = "jamie@sharpsdigital.co.uk";

$sub = "Contact Form Enquiry";

$headers  = "From: Star Tyres <jamie@sharpsdigital.co.uk>"."\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email." \r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion()."\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message = '<h4>New Contact Form Enquiry : </h4>
            <p>Name: '.$first_name.'</p>
            <p>Email: '.$email.'</p>
            <p>Subject: '.$subject.'</p>
            <p>Message: '.$message.'</p><br>
            ';

$mail = mail($to, $sub, $message, $headers, 'jamie@sharpsdigital.co.uk');

if ( $mail)
{
    header('Location: contact.html?var=sent');
}
else
{
    /* error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    echo 'error';
    print_r(error_get_last()); */
    header('Location: contact.html?var=error');
}
```

This one is my php, I have linked up both with using the action="sendmail.php" and using the method post. However when I got to click the button and send it just seems to go to *.com/sendmail.php and I dont get an email. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE ==============================

After a few comments I have tried to tweak a few things. im now getting the echo command back once I hit the submit button but nothing else.

```
<?php
  extract($_POST);
  echo "Made it to sendmail.php";
  if( isset($_POST['submit']))
  {



$mailTo = "jamie@sharpsdigital.co.uk";

$sub = "Contact Form Enquiry";

$headers  = "From: Star Tyres <jamie@sharpsdigital.co.uk>"."\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email." \r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion()."\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message = '<h4>New Contact Form Enquiry : </h4>
            <p>Name: '.$first_name.'</p>
            <p>Email: '.$email.'</p>
            <p>Subject: '.$sub.'</p>
            <p>Message: '.$message.'</p><br>
            ';

$mail = mail($to, $sub, $message, $headers, 'jamie@sharpsdigital.co.uk');



 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Do you have a `<form>` tag with it set to post?

Comment: <form action="sendmail.php" method="POST" class="contact-form" novalidate="novalidate">

Comment: The form has a method of post. Is that the right attribute to use?

Comment: Yes form method=post.  You could, in sendmail.php, add `echo "Made it to sendmail.php";` just to make sure it is at least calling the correct code.

Comment: Also it looks like you may be using some incorrect variables.  In `$message` you have a reference to `$subject` instead of `$sub`.  And `$email` appears to be undefined

Comment: Right so I have changed $subject to sub and email is already defined?  <p>Email: '.$email.'</p> ix this how is it suppose to be?

Comment: Whatever im doing now im losing progress from what I had before.

Comment: Sorry, correction to my earlier post...  assuming `<input type=textbox name=email/>` try, in sendmail.php, `$email = $_POST['email']` will set the value of the email textbox to the variable `$email`

Comment: I dont think that is doing anything once I put this into my php I then lose the echo

Comment: under `$to = "jamie@sharpsdigital.co.uk";` add this line `$email = $_POST['email']`

Comment: and remove the `echo` entirely or comment it out

Comment: I have removed the echo and put the $email command under it nothing seemed to change still having the same problem

Comment: @Jamie a button is not a form element. Either you trigger the submit with a javascript or you change the button to an input type button. your first if in the php will work only if you use the second option

Comment: @LelioFaieta so I should change the button to <button type="input" ? This is my first time trying to use php

Comment: no, input type button. @Jamie

Comment: @LelioFaieta So the entire command looks like this?  <button type="submit" input-type="button" data-type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button> is this correct?

Comment: no, see my answer. If this fix your issue consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: is `sendmail` installed on your server? Not all server's come with a pre-configured SMTP server ...

Comment: A colleague has told me its installed on our sever

Comment: @Jamie but have you checked? No disrespect to your colleague but what one says and what one is are two very different things

Comment: See the answer below I managed to get an email send from the form

Answer (score 1):

Change your button to submit the form to this:

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

`input` is an element of a form, a button no. The name is what you will look for in the php (`$_POST['submit']`)

The value attribute is what will be displayed inside the button

Comment: nice catch, I was completely overlooking that

Comment: OP can rollback to his previous code that should be working fine this way

Comment: Changing this doesnt even go to the php anymore. Acts as a blank button

Comment: If I use my orignal code for my php and this new change everthing should work?

Answer (score 0):

HTH

```
<?php
  extract($_POST);

  if( isset($_POST['submit']))
  {


$email = $_POST['email'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$to = "jamie@sharpsdigital.co.uk";

$sub = "Contact Form Enquiry";


$headers  = "From: Star Tyres <jamie@sharpsdigital.co.uk>"."\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email." \r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion()."\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message = '<h4>New Contact Form Enquiry : </h4>
            <p>Name: '.$first_name.'</p>
            <p>Email: '.$email.'</p>
            <p>Subject: '.$sub.'</p>
            <p>Message: '.$message.'</p><br>
            ';

$mail = mail($to, $sub, $message, $headers, 'jamie@sharpsdigital.co.uk');



 }

?>
```

or, more simply:

```
<?php
$to      = 'jamie@sharpsdigital.co.uk';
$subject = 'Contact Form Enquiry';
$message = '<h4>New Contact Form Enquiry : </h4>
            <p>Name: '.$_POST['first_name'].'</p>
            <p>Email: '.$_POST['email'].'</p>
            <p>Subject: '.$subject .'</p>
            <p>Message: '.$_POST['message'].'</p><br>
            ';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ".$_POST['email']' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

TESTING PURPOSE:

create new file `testemail.php` and input this code:

```
<?php
$to      = 'jamie@sharpsdigital.co.uk';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: no-reply@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

then browse to page and see if you received an e-mail after...

Comment: Same problem.  im pretty my problem is to do with the button on my form not starting the process

Comment: If the echo worked previously then your submit button is working correctly. Is this on a remote server?  `mail()` will not work in a local server

Comment: This is on a live domain

Comment: And I put the echo back in you are right, im still getting that text line when I hit the submit button the problem must be with the starting  if( isset($_POST['submit']))

Comment: @Jamie I edited my post.  See TESTING PURPOSES -- that might confirm mail() is working properly

Comment: Okay your testing purpose one worked I have got an email using my original code and simply just changing the php to this new one

Comment: Could I also ask what the problem was with my other Php code block?

Comment: And with your new testemail.php how should I send the data from my fields into this email?